# MVC 5 Redirect to Login Page Not Working with OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I'm trying to get my head around using OWIN.  I have created two MVC 5 projects.  One with authentication using Aspnet.Identity and the other started as an empty project.

I added the following to the emptyp project:

- Account controller with a Login action and coresponding view
- Startup.cs and another partial Startup.cs with

```cs
public partial class Startup
{
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });
        }
    }
```

I have decorated the About action in the Home controller with the [Authorize] attribute in both projects.

When I run the first project and go to the About screen before logging in it redirects to the login action as expect.  When I do the same for the second project I get a "HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized" instead of redirecting.

Any idea what would cause the second one to behave this way?

Comment: Have you compared the web.config between the two projects?

Comment: I have compared the two web.config files, but I'll do it again and report back...

Comment: @AlexDresko, thanks for the help.  I did find some differences in the web.config that I missed yesterday.  Unfortunately it didn't help solve the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I’ve created two new similar projects and was able to reproduce your error.

In the blank project, I had to install the `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` (via Nuget) and once I did this, I was getting a bunch of errors in my Startup.cs class. Ended up with this:

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(v2.Startup))]
namespace v2
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });
        }
    }
}
```

In the end, I'm now capable of hitting/seeing my Login view when I call the About() method decorated with the `[Authorize]` attribute.

Hope this helps!
Vince

Comment: thanks for spending the time to try this.  I started clean again and was finally able to track down two different problems.  In one project that I was trying this on I had "AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive" in the CookieAuthenticationOptions.  This was left over from something else I was trying.  In another project I forgot to call Startup.ConfigureAuth() from Startup.Configuration()!  So basically two careless mistakes.  I'm back on track and trying to figure out the next issue....

Answer (score 8):

Per [ASP.NET MVC 5 Web.config: "FormsAuthenticationModule" or "FormsAuthentication"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652808/asp-net-mvc-5-web-config-formsauthenticationmodule-or-formsauthentication/22772647#22772647)

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

for extra safety I left both the "typo" handler in (in case Microsoft changes it later giving me)

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
     <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
     <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: what does this line of code will do   <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />

Comment: click on the link in my answer where it is explained.  My answer had also been deleted so it was not there prior.

Comment: When I accessed my site : XYZ.com I always got redirected to XYZ.com/En/Login?returnUrl=%F2. You just solved this, my provider OnApplyRedirect is now called. I wanted to intercept this call and make sure to not returnUrl on useless locations.