# ASP.NET MVC 5 Web.config: "FormsAuthenticationModule" or "FormsAuthentication"

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8, owin

Ok so this not a big deal, but it's bugging me and I can't let it go.

So I'm using MVC 5.1 with .NET 4.5.1 and OWIN authentication. So when you create a new MVC 5 project, the following is automatically added to the Web.config to get rid of the forms authentication http module because it is no longer needed when using OWIN middleware:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Now since we are removing the module, that means it was previously added, so here is the entry registering this http module in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config`:

```
<httpModules>
    <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
</httpModules>
```

And here is the entry in `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` for IIS 8.5 that tells my application to use the module:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

So what is automatically added to my web config at the application level has a name attribute of "FormsAuthenticationModule" while the entries in the two server level/asp.net level config files use name attribute "FormsAuthentication". So what is going on here? It seems to me that the module won't be removed since the name attribute doesn't match. I would simply think this was a typo, but after searching online, everyone seems to be using "FormsAuthenticationModule" in the application web.config. Was this a recent change in the newer version of asp.net / iis or am I missing something?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're right -- that's a typo in the template.

Comment: They fixed it :)

Answer (score 9):

A major side effect of this "typo" is it will leave FormsAuthentication on causing loginpath of owin to be ignored and calls to authenticated pages going to /login.aspx

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Speaking of typos... I think u meant ‘unauthenticated pages’ ;-)

Comment: @Simon_Weaver I think Aaron was referring to pages requiring authentication.  Unauthenticated pages wouldn't require a login ;-)

Comment: @SamIam I think this answer adds more information to help users solve the problem since the side affect isn't mentioned by the OP or in the accepted answer but will definitely occur causing some confused dev to go off and fire up StackOverflow.