# How can I restore Forms Authentication via Web.config in an MVC 5 app using ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I'm in the early stages of building an app with MVC 5. I haven't used this version of the framework yet, nor ASP.NET Identity (I'm not even sure if that's relevant to my problem). I want to temporarily, *temporarily*, hard code a user in the web.config as follows:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880">
    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
      <user name="name" password="password"/>
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

I've used that previously, and it's worked as expected. In this app, however, it's not working. In `AccountController.cs`, in the method `Login()`, it appears that an object of type `UserManager` can't find the user I specified in web.config, probably because that object isn't looking in web.config.

So, how I do re-enable using the user specified in web.config? Please provide steps.

I completely understand that this not a good practice. It's only temporary to get something else working.

Comment: Asp.Net Identity completely replace FormsAuthentication, therefore anything you try to do with FormsAuthentication will be unknown to Asp.Net Identity.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - Correct. However, I believe it may have more to do with the OWIN middleware than strictly ASP.NET Identity. (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/07/03/understanding-owin-forms-authentication-in-mvc-5.aspx) You should be removing the module, as specified here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652808/asp-net-mvc-5-web-config-formsauthenticationmodule-or-formsauthentication

Comment: @ErikPhilips OK, then. How about this? Is there a way I can do something similar with ASP.NET Identity? I.e. hardcode a user account somewhere.

Comment: Maybe create a controller method that creates an external claims/bearer token for login?  Either way the user really should exist in the DB.

Comment: The Seed() method, perhaps? I'll look into that. Thanks Erik.