# Using Owin authentication; not redirected to LoginPath

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

Ran into a frustrating problem with ASP.NET Identity. The app does not redirect to the `LoginPath`, but instead serves a 401.

I've added the `AuthorizeAttribute` filter to my filters and the `AllowAnonymous` attribute to the Login action.

I have refactored `Configuration()` method in `Startup.cs` to:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ConfigureAuth(app);
}

public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
        LoginPath = new PathString("/user/login")
    });
}
```

as per this question:
[MVC 5 Redirect to Login Page Not Working with OWIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647752/mvc-5-redirect-to-login-page-not-working-with-owin)

I have edited the web.config file, and added the lines:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</system.webServer>
```

as per this question: [ASP.NET MVC 5 Web.config: "FormsAuthenticationModule" or "FormsAuthentication"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652808/asp-net-mvc-5-web-config-formsauthenticationmodule-or-formsauthentication/22772647#22772647)

I still don't get redirects. On the other side, I have no clue what these fine gentlemen are talking about: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/607

Apparently this line should be solving my problem:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options => {
    options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
    options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
});
```

The package that contains `UseCookieAuthentication` override that accepts lambdas or the `AutomaticAuthenticate` and `AutomaticChallenge` options is, I assume, `Microsof.AspNet.Authentication` and `Microsof.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies`, but both are missing from NuGet.

The web.config contains the owin key: `<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="SmartKG.App_Start.Startup" />`

EDIT: One peculiar thing I did not mention: Before I've added the `UserController`, which contains the Login action, I was getting redirected to the proper route, but was getting the missing resource error of course. Once I've added the controller and the action, problems with redirecting started to happen.

Comment: Do you have <authentication mode="Forms" /> in the system.web section of your web.config?

Comment: Do you have the OWIN startup in the web.config? `<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="<Namespace>.Startup" />` http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection

Comment: Just to double check, Did you add [Authorize] attribute on the method or the controller you are trying to restrict access too ?

Comment: @BoydP yes, I've edited the question to point that out, thanks.

Comment: @hsanivag I don't think that's necessary since I've added the AuthorizeAttribute filter. Doesn't that make every controller and action deny unauthorized access? Also, I'm getting a 401 once I'm not redirected.

Comment: To my knowledge you need to still decorate the controller and do you have user controller ? i think your login is in account controller  correct  Try changing loging path as below  LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/login")